# Calculate sum data and insert into another in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate sum of hours based on period column and insert into another table. Please see below example data.
[code]

### tbl_Summary

```
    Client_id   Store_id    attribute1  Period    Hours     attributes
1              16             1        2/25/2007  1054.8     1
1              16             1        3/11/2007  1112.8     1
1              16             1        3/25/2007  1164.8     1
1              16             1        4/8/2007   1383.2     1
1              16             1        4/22/2007  1351.6     1
1            16       1          9/21/2008      1523.6       1**
1            16       1         10/5/2008      1020.26   1
1            16       1         10/19/2008      939.94   1
1            16       1         11/2/2008       903.14   1
1            16       1         8/9/2009        866.66   1
1            16       1         8/23/2009       915.48   1
1            16       1         9/6/2009        894.26   1
1            16       1         9/20/2009      1458.58   1[/b]
1              18             1        6/1/2008   1112.8     1
1              18             1        6/15/2008  1164.8     1
1              18             1        6/29/2008  1383.2     1 [b]
1            18        1     7/13/2008 1351.6    1
1            18        1    12/28/2008 1523.6    1
1            18        1     1/11/2009  979.2    1
1            18        1     1/25/2009  913.2    1
1            18        1     2/8/2009   930.6    1
1            18        1     2/22/2009 1143.4    1
1            18        1     5/31/2009 1066.16   1
1            18        1     6/14/2009  1174.8   1
1            18        1     6/28/2009  1099.2   1
1            18        1     7/12/2009  1014.5   1
```

Out put table will be like this.

```
tbl_history
--------------
[code]client_id store_id    attribute1  hours   attributes
1                    16          1         8521.92    1
1                    18          1        11196.92    1
```

Conditions for sp

1. Parameters to sp are only @client_id, @attribute1, @attributes
2. Find Max(Period) and go back to 52 weeks and calculate Sum(Hours)  where Store_id= ? (in example 16 and 18 or each store_id) and client_id= @client_id and attribute1 = @attribute1 and attributes = @attributes. ie. Sum(Hours) will change based on store_id and when store_id will change period will change. **See side moved data**

store_id = 16 and period=9/20/2009 to 9/20/2009 sum(hours) =8521.92

1. Insert into another table all output tbl_history.

Please give me solution. If you have any question ask me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  It feels like you have been given an assignment and you want us to do your work for you.  I'm sure that isn't the case, but it would be helpful to know where you are having trouble and what you have tried.

Comment: It is my project only. But the thing is ... I am stuck at stored_id. Because Store_id not passed in SP parameters. How to get that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_history
SELECT client_id, store_id, attribute1, SUM(Hours), attributes
FROM tbl_Summary
WHERE PERIOD <=
(
    SELECT MAX(PERIOD)
    FROM tbl_Summary
    WHERE client_id = @client_id
    AND attribute1 = @attribute1
    AND attributes = @attributes
)
AND PERIOD  >= 
(
    SELECT (MAX(PERIOD) - 1 year) --(I dont remember the sintax for sql getdate() something but thats the idea)
    FROM tbl_Summary
    WHERE client_id = @client_id
    AND attribute1 = @attribute1
    AND attributes = @attributes
)
AND client_id = @client_id
AND attribute1 = @attribute1
AND attributes = @attributes
GROUP BY client_id, store_id, attribute1, attributes
```

Try it and tell me if it worked.

Regards.